# Rails 4 - Preloading has_many through association fails with lambda conditions of through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have the following structure and am trying to `include` a `has_many :through` association. It works properly if I don't preload the `collections`, but then I'm faced with an `N+1` problem.

How can I pass conditions of the parent `products` association into the lambda when selecting `collections`?

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: products
  #  name                :string(255)      not null

  has_many    :products,
                inverse_of:     :collection

  has_many    :product_lines,
                through:        :products,
                inverse_of:     :products

  has_many    :lines,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: products
  #  active              :boolean          default(TRUE), not null

  belongs_to  :collection,
                inverse_of:     :products

  has_many    :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product

  has_many    :lines,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines
end


class ProductLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :product,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines

  belongs_to  :line,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines
end


class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :line

  has_many    :products,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines

  # Gets Collections through Products where `product.active = true`
  # And orders the Collections by `collection.name`
  has_many    :collections,
                -> { where( products: {active: true} ).order(name: :ASC) },
                through:        :products,
                inverse_of:     :products

end
```

Works:

```
Line.all.each{ |line| line.collections }
```

Doesn't work:

```
Line.includes(:collections).all.each{ |line| line.collections }
```

Throws error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "products"."...
                                                        ^
: SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "products"."active" = $1 AND "collections"."id" IN (11, 30, 27, 12, 10, 13, 6, 4, 2, 7, 15, 9, 19, 1, 14, 8, 31, 5, 3, 29, 20, 17, 16, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 18, 44, 45, 26, 24, 25, 21, 22, 23):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just an idiot. All I had to do is `include(:products)` in the lambda. The working solution is below, and was further DRYed up by moving the logic for selecting `collections` through `products` into the named scope `:by_active_products` on `Collections`. Both methods work with preloading and neither causes an `N+1` issue.

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: products
  #  name                :string(255)      not null

  has_many    :products,
                inverse_of:     :collection

  has_many    :product_lines,
                through:        :products,
                inverse_of:     :products

  has_many    :lines,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines

  scope       :by_active_products, -> () { 
                includes(:products)
                .where({products: {active: true}})
                .order(name: :ASC)
                .uniq
              }
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: products
  #  active              :boolean          default(TRUE), not null

  belongs_to  :collection,
                inverse_of:     :products

  has_many    :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product

  has_many    :lines,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines
end


class ProductLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :product,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines

  belongs_to  :line,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines
end


class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :line

  has_many    :products,
                through:        :product_lines,
                inverse_of:     :product_lines

  # Gets Collections through Products where `product.active = true`
  # And orders the Collections by `collection.name`
  has_many    :collections,
                # Working using a named scope in the Collection model
                ->              { Collection.by_active_products },
                # Also working; Query params directly in the lambda
                # -> { includes(:products).where(products: {active: true}).order(name: :ASC).uniq },
                through:        :products,
                inverse_of:     :products

end
```

Working now:

```
Line.includes(:collections).all.each{ |line| line.collections }
```